# Text fades in on hover background darkens

Tags: javascript, html, css

Demo: http://jleblanc.pancakeapps.com/index.html

all html/css in page source.

I am making a website for my mom and I am trying to hide the text on the .one .two and .three divs until the mouse hovers over them. I am trying to make the background fade to rgba(0,0,0,0.6) on hover as well. I am not very skilled with javascript either. Does anyone have an idea on how I could do it?

/ EDIT- I want the *text* to fade in from the background, sorry for the confusion. /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fading text do this:

```
.one section{
    transition: opacity 1s;
    height: 100%;
}
.one section:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

For fading both background and text try this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/dZMKt/

I made a simple example based on your code. The only change you need to do - add "one_wrapper" div around "one"-div.

Read more about [css3-transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You do not want javascript for this.Modify your classes as following.

```
.one {
   text-indent:-9999px;
}


.one:hover {
   text-indent:0;
}
```

Comment: I like your idea, but is there anyway to smooth the transition? Maybe it could fade in instead of such a jump?